# Caching all images on external site through Cloudflare

Tags: caching, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

Here is my situation:

I have a webapp that uses a lot of images on a remote server. My webapp is behind Cloudflare, although the server that the images are hosted on are not.. and this server can be very slow. It can sometimes take about 5 seconds per image.

I would like to use Cloudflare to proxy requests to this external server, but also cache them indefinitely, or at least as long as possible. The images never change so I do not mind them having a long cache life.

Is this something I should set up in a worker? As a page rule? Or just not use CLoudflare in this way?

Answer (score 3):

If you can't change origin server headers, you could try following snippet in your worker:

```js
fetch(event.request, { cf: { cacheTtl: 300 } })
```

As per [docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/reference/cloudflare-features/):

> This option forces Cloudflare to cache the response for this request,
>   regardless of what headers are seen on the response. This is
>   equivalent to setting two page rules: “Edge Cache TTL” and “Cache
>   Level” (to “Cache Everything”).

Answer (score 0):

I think you generally just want a very long caching header on your images. Something like:

```
Cache-Control: public; max-age=31536000
```

Comment: The problem is I don't have access to the server serving the images. It's on a different domain, going through a different CDN 